# Webservice request: Mismatched parameter count

Tags: java, web-services, parameters, jax-ws

I am writing a webservice consumer using JAX-WS. I've used wsimport tool in order to generate the code from the WSDL files.

In this webservice I have 4 operations, 1 of which works. This operations asks just for a parameter and it works right

```
MyOperationARequest request = new MyOperationARequest(); 
request.setSomeData("1");

MyOperationAResponse response = serviceA.MyOperationA(request);
```

This works like a charm and I am able to parse the response and get the data from it.

The problem comes when using the other 3 operations, all of them asking for two parameters instead of one.

```
MyOperationBRequest request = new MyOperationBRequest(); 
request.setSomeData("1");

MyOperationBResponse response = serviceB.MyOperationB(request1, request2);
```

This throws me the following error:

```
javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Mismatched parameter count:expecting 1 items, but got 0 instead.
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.fault.SOAP11Fault.getProtocolException(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.fault.SOAPFaultBuilder.createException(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.invoke(Unknown Source)
at $Proxy34.myOperation(Unknown Source)
...
```

I've been searching a lot and I found some problems like this one, although all of them were in PHP, not Java. In this examples people encourage to create an array and put there the two parameters, but I believe this is not an option because the method myOperationB is asking me for two of them (which, by the way, are not even the same object type).

Any suggestion will be much appreciated.

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: From message it is evident that your Service MyOperationBRequest has operation MyOperationB with only one parameter. Please post your WSDL operations part.

Comment: thanks for your response. 

     `<wsdl:message name="MyOperationBRequest">
  <wsdl:part element="header:someHeader" name="header" />
  <wsdl:part element="body:someBody" name="body" />
 </wsdl:message>`

As you can see, it asks me for a header and the body of the message. Each one of these parts are created on the code using classes generated by the wsimport tool.

Thanks!